# More efficient way of finding edit distance over a large array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a large array of words (300k words) and I want to find the edit distance between each word, so I was just iterating over it and doing running through this version of the levenstein algorithm:

```
unsigned int edit_distance(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    const std::size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> d(len1 + 1, std::vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));
d[0][0] = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = i;
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= len2; ++i) d[0][i] = i;

for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i)
    for (unsigned int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j)
        // note that std::min({arg1, arg2, arg3}) works only in C++11,
        // for C++98 use std::min(std::min(arg1, arg2), arg3)
        d[i][j] = std::min({ d[i - 1][j] + 1, d[i][j - 1] + 1, d[i - 1][j - 1] + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1) });
return d[len1][len2];
}
```

So what I was wondering is, if there was a more efficient way of doing this, I heard about Levenshtein Autonoma but I wasn't sure if that would be any more efficient.

I would imagine that there you could avoid processing the same thing over and over again by preprocessing something but I have no idea how to actually achieve it (some approximate calculations would be to preprocess everything would be around 10^28 operations so that would not be an improvement)

Comment: And you have 300k *different* words?

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah its from the word list off stack overflow, although I need that many for my project

Comment: @Cjen1 I think BoPersson means that you should use a set/dictionary to filter the duplicated words first.

Comment: @ShaneLu There are no duplicates, unfortunately I can't find the original post but yeah its actually 350k words

Comment: Sorry please ignore this comment.

Comment: @ShaneLu I'm not sure if that will help or if it will break the algorithm, since its my understanding that the dp algorithm requires all subproblems to be solved for the solution to be achieved

Comment: My previous comment was totally wrong, please ignore it.

Comment: The immediate problem you face is that the answer is very nearly 45 *billion* numbers -- one edit distance for every unordered pair of words.  So e.g. 45Gb of results if you use 1 byte for each distance.  Even if there was a CPU instruction that could compute the Levenshtein distance, this will take a while.

Comment: @Cjen1: Do you want to find the distance between all pairs? What would you do with it? Maybe you need only certain pairs (e.g. the ones with the smallest / largest distance)?

Comment: @LiorKogan yeah so I'm trying to find all the pairs which have an edit distance of less than 2 so there is some pruning that I can do such as comparing lengths

Comment: @Cjen1: You can also exploit the fact that L(A,C)<=L(A,B)+L(B,C) see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368112/is-levenshtein-distance-transitive). But please update your question if this is what you're after.

Comment: @LiorKogan the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Cjen1: L(A,B)>=L(A,C)-L(B,C), so if L(A,C)-L(B,C)>2 you can skip checking L(A,B).

Comment: @LiorKogan That's awesome, I'll definitely have to implement that, if yo want to put that in as an answer I think that is basically the solution that I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in his comment, The OP is actually looking for all the pairs with edit distance of less than 2.

Given an input of n words, a naive approach would be to make n(n-1)/2 comparisons, but less comparison may be required when L in an edit distance which is a [metric space for strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance#Properties).

Levenshtein distance is a metric space, and satisfies the 4 required metric axioms - including the triangle inequality.

**Edit:**

Given this, we can use the method proposed by Sergey Brin (Google's co-founder) in his paper [Near Neighbor Search in Large Metric Spaces](http://www.vldb.org/conf/1995/P574.PDF) back in 1995, to solve our problem.

Quoting from the paper: Given a metric space (X, d), a data set Y ⊆ X, a query point x ∈ X, and a range r ∈ R, the near neighbors of x are the set of points y ∈ Y, such that d(x, y) ≤ r.

In this paper, Brin introduced GNAT (Geometric Near-neighbor Access Tree) - a data structure to solve this problem. Brin actually test the performance of his algorithm using the Levenshtein distance (which he calls "Edit distance") against two text corpora.

Over the years GNAT become well-known and widely used. Some improvements to GNAT where suggested in [Geometric Near-neighbor Access Tree (GNAT) revisited](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05944v1.pdf) - Fredriksson 2016.

Answer (score 1):

If as indicated in the comments what you actually want is to find pairs with edit distance at most two, you can generate from each word all possibilities of deleting at most two characters (should be at most 500 or so), and store these in a hash table. Then, you only need to check each pair of words in a hash bucket, which is probably not hard to do by looking at whether deletions coincide.

Comment: The issue with the problem is that the computation time to generate all pair of distance 2 is taking me around 32 hours and any time I make any changes to the database format or accidentally delete the database file I need to rerun the program to generate the pairs

Comment: But the method I described does not require to calculate all pairs, but only ask pairs in a bucket. Since any two words in a bucket have edit distance at most 4, the largest bucket should have considerably less than 300,000 elements to pair.

Comment: This approach is still brute force in nature.